# Create user account in local AD on SharePoint Online list form submission

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, ad

I need to implement a solution where a user submits a SharePoint Online list form and with those details we should create a local AD user account. I am fine if this could be implemented as a scheduler, not necessary the code should trigger quickly on list item added. I need your expert advise to implement the best possible solution for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Using sharepoint client side object read the new items created (have a column that will hold info that account is created like created, bool) Then using AD - Powershell module read those values and create account after creation update SharePoint list item. Then run this script as a job from server that can communicate with SPonline and your domain controller.